# How to setup IOS and Android universal link on Angular project

Tags: angular

I created `.well-known` file under the src and put `assetlinks.json file` inside to `.well-known`. After configurated `angular.json` file as follows. When I call the url `http://localhost:4200/.well-known/assetlinks.json` redirected to 404 page. I want to public assetlinks.json file. How can I solve?

```
        "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/p",
        "index": "src/index.html",
        "main": "src/main.ts",
        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
        "aot": true,
        "assets": [
          {
            "glob": "**/*",
            "input": "src/.well-known",
            "output": ".well-known/"
          },
          "src/favicon.ico",
          "src/assets"
        ],
        "styles": [
          "src/styles.scss"
        ],
        "scripts": []
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

The url is worked after build project. Well-known file created under `dist`.